# Blueimp jQuery File Upload not compatible with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, blueimp

I am trying to integrate the Blueimp jQuery File upload in ASP.NET Core 3.1 but it has become incompatible with this version (3.1).

The reason why I am saying is because I have tested the same code with ASP.NET Core 2.0 where Blueimp works perfectly. The below are the 2 videos to prove this fact.

**ASP.NET Core 2.0 which works perfectly**
[image]

**ASP.NET Core 3.1 which gives error**
[image]

**The Controller's code in ASP.NET Core 3.1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using jFileUpload.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace jFileUpload.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
        public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            hostingEnvironment = environment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonFiles> Upload(IFormFile files)
        {
            var resultList = new List<UploadFilesResult>();

            string path = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads/" + files.FileName);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await files.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }

            UploadFilesResult uploadFiles = new UploadFilesResult();
            uploadFiles.name = files.FileName;
            uploadFiles.size = files.Length;
            uploadFiles.type = "image/jpeg";
            uploadFiles.url = "/uploads/" + files.FileName;
            uploadFiles.deleteUrl = "/Home/Delete?file=" + files.FileName;
            uploadFiles.thumbnailUrl = "/uploads/" + files.FileName;
            uploadFiles.deleteType = "GET";

            resultList.Add(uploadFiles);

            JsonFiles jFiles = new JsonFiles(resultList);
            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jFiles);
            return jFiles;
        }

        public JsonResult Delete(string file)
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads/" + file));
            return Json("OK");
        }
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 the controllers code is slightly different on the Dependency Injection part which is given below, rest all is same.

```
private IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
{
    hostingEnvironment = environment;
}
```

**The Model classes**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace jFileUpload.Models
{
    public class UploadFilesResult
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public long size { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string deleteUrl { get; set; }
        public string thumbnailUrl { get; set; }
        public string deleteType { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace jFileUpload.Models
{
    public class JsonFiles
    {
        public UploadFilesResult[] files;
        public string TempFolder { get; set; }
        public JsonFiles(List<UploadFilesResult> filesList)
        {
            files = new UploadFilesResult[filesList.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < filesList.Count; i++)
            {
                files[i] = filesList.ElementAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The View code**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Demo
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
    <!--[if IE]>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery File Upload Demo</title>
    <meta name="description"
          content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and client-side image resizing. Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads." />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Bootstrap styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
          crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- Generic page styles -->
    <style>
      #navigation {
        margin: 10px 0;
      }
      @@media (max-width: 767px) {
        #title,
        #description {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <!-- blueimp Gallery styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css" />
    <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.fileupload.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" />
    <!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.fileupload-noscript.css" />
    </noscript>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css" />
    </noscript>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">Project</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">Demo</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki">Wiki</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="https://blueimp.net">Author</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h1 id="title">jQuery File Upload Demo</h1>
        <blockquote id="description">
            <p>
                File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop
                support, progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video
                for jQuery.<br />
                Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and
                client-side image resizing.<br />
                Works with any server-side platform (PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java,
                Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.
            </p>
        </blockquote>
        <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <form id="fileupload"
              action="https://jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/"
              method="POST"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
            <noscript>
                <input type="hidden"
                       name="redirect"
                       value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/" />
            </noscript>
            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete selected</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" />
                    <!-- The global file processing state -->
                    <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- The global progress state -->
                <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active"
                         role="progressbar"
                         aria-valuemin="0"
                         aria-valuemax="100">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"
                             style="width: 0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                    <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
            <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped">
                <tbody class="files"></tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Demo Notes</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        The maximum file size for uploads in this demo is
                        <strong>999 KB</strong> (default file size is unlimited).
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Only image files (<strong>JPG, GIF, PNG</strong>) are allowed in
                        this demo (by default there is no file type restriction).
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Uploaded files will be deleted automatically after
                        <strong>5 minutes or less</strong> (demo files are stored in
                        memory).
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        You can <strong>drag &amp; drop</strong> files from your desktop
                        on this webpage (see
                        <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Browser-support">Browser support</a>).
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Please refer to the
                        <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload">project website</a>
                        and
                        <a href="https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki">documentation</a>
                        for more information.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Built with the
                        <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/">Bootstrap</a> CSS framework
                        and Icons from <a href="https://glyphicons.com/">Glyphicons</a>.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
    <div id="blueimp-gallery"
         class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls"
         aria-label="image gallery"
         aria-modal="true"
         role="dialog"
         data-filter=":even">
        <div class="slides" aria-live="polite"></div>
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <a class="prev"
           aria-controls="blueimp-gallery"
           aria-label="previous slide"
           aria-keyshortcuts="ArrowLeft"></a>
        <a class="next"
           aria-controls="blueimp-gallery"
           aria-label="next slide"
           aria-keyshortcuts="ArrowRight"></a>
        <a class="close"
           aria-controls="blueimp-gallery"
           aria-label="close"
           aria-keyshortcuts="Escape"></a>
        <a class="play-pause"
           aria-controls="blueimp-gallery"
           aria-label="play slideshow"
           aria-keyshortcuts="Space"
           aria-pressed="false"
           role="button"></a>
        <ol class="indicator"></ol>
    </div>
    <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
    <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade{%=o.options.loadImageFileTypes.test(file.type)?' image':''%}">
            <td>
                <span class="preview"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="size">Processing...</p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (!o.options.autoUpload && o.options.edit && o.options.loadImageFileTypes.test(file.type)) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-success edit" data-index="{%=i%}" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                    <span>Edit</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
                {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
                {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% } %}
    </script>
    <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
        {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade{%=file.thumbnailUrl?' image':''%}">
            <td>
                <span class="preview">
                    {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                    {% } %}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">
                    {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                    {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                    {% } %}
                </p>
                {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
                {% } %}
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}" {% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}' {% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
                {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% } %}
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
    <script src="~/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
    <script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <!-- blueimp Gallery script -->
    <script src="https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload processing plugin -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload image preview & resize plugin -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload audio preview plugin -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.fileupload-audio.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload video preview plugin -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.fileupload-video.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload validation plugin -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
    <script src="~/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- The main application script -->
    <script src="~/js/demo.js"></script>
    <!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE 8 and IE 9 -->
    <!--[if (gte IE 8)&(lt IE 10)]>
      <script src="~/js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the ASP.NET Core 3.1 I get the error -

- "Empty file upload result"

Why it is so ?. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: JQuery is client side. Do you get that error from client side or from your controller? Have you used F12 console to investigate if there is a client side issue? What line of your code throws this error?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no problem with the controller. It is called and it returns the class object to the view. Error is from jQuery. The image however is getting uploaded (as controller works perfectly) but error comes from jQuery.

Comment: So everything works but javascript is returning an error? The controller code would appear to be irrelavant in this case,  unless the controller is returning an error that the javascript is reacting to. So I suggest you use the network tab to inspect the post and result for both cases and see if there any differences

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I checked the networks tab for both the cases and I do not find any errors. There are just lot's of request to various JS files and it's very difficult to find out the cause.

Comment: Well something in the javascript must literally have that text in it, or it's echoing that text as returned by the controller.

Comment: If you search the git, here's the code that throws that error: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/search?q=%22Empty+file+upload+result%22&unscoped_q=%22Empty+file+upload+result%22

Comment: Basically the two different controllers are returning different things to the javascript.

Comment: I did managed to search for the static code text in the VS and found out that the file called "jquery.fileupload-ui.js" has this text. I Also checked for the response for this js file in the networks tab but did not find any error or anything special.

Comment: The link you shared I did find this file to contain this code but on the networks tab there aren't any error for this file's response.

Comment: No there won't be any error response. There will be a success reponse that returns JSON, and in that JSON there's a data structure that makes it think that no files were uploaded. If you can compare the actual response JSON data you'll see they are different between versions. I don't know why though.

Comment: Basically this line: `return jFiles;` is returning two different things between versions. The data structure returned is different for some reason.

Comment: I could not find any json respnse in the network's tab. I also check the value for `return jFiles` code in the controller. I check it by putting this code (`string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jFiles);`) to convert it to string value. The json string I got in both cases was totally same.

Comment: Next I suggest you put a breakpoint on the JScript code that throws the error and inspect the values that trigger it. Referring to the source, line 172 captures the ajax response in variable `data`. Then by line 185 it gets processed in various ways.

Comment: I placed breakpoint on line 185 - `var file = files[index] || { error: 'Empty file upload result' }`. The value for `files[index]` is Array(0) where it throws the error (for Core 3.1). In core 2.0 it has value. The jQuery is failing to get proper response from controller in 3.1 version of .NET Core. But I really can't find it.

Comment: You need to check the value of `data` way up at line 172 and compare between versions. Perhaps put the breakpoint there. We are iteratively isolating the difference here.

Comment: @yogihosting Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @yogihosting which version of Blueimp are you using now?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked back at the source codes in my pc. I found that I went with 2.0 version of ASP.NET Core version which worked properly with the newest Blueimp version. ASP.NET Core 3.1 version continued to have this problem. So the only solution which I found is to use 2.0 version.

Comment: @yogihosting I believe the issue is in the format of jfiles are being returned. I was able to get the basic functionality of the upload working with Core 3.1 after making the change to the return format. I will test it with m main code and if it does work post an answer hre.

Comment: @The_Outsider will wait for your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be that with ASP.Net Core 3, there looks like there is a change in how the value needs to be sent back to the upload function.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Upload(IFormFile files)
{
    var resultList = new List<UploadFilesResult>();
    .
    .
    //Your code
    .
    .
    resultList.Add(uploadFiles);

    //This is the new change, the new format which you have to send the data back as.   
    return Json(new { files = resultList });
}
```

The script portion of the Upload will remain the same. I used your code in your website and this change worked fine with your solution too.

Comment: I get the errror - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'jFileUpload.Models.JsonFiles' jFileUpload". How to solve?

Comment: @yogihosting I have edited the answer. Change the return type to Task<JsonResult> instead of the existing Task<JsonFiles> in your code.